# Converse of mean value theorem almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function.

We say a point $c \in \mathbb R$ is a *mean value point* of $f$ if there exists an open interval $(a,b)$ containing $c$ such that $f’(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.

> **Question:** Is it true that (Lebesgue) almost every point in $\mathbb R$ is a mean value point of $f$?

Comment: Does the following work? Let $U$ be an open and dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with finite measure (e.g. union of shortening balls around rationals), and let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ be a continuous function so that $\{g = 0\} = U^c$. Then define $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = g(0)+\int_0^x g(t)dt$. Then $f' = g$, so $f \in C^1$, and $f$ is strictly increasing since for any $x < y$, there's some open interval contained in $U$ lying inside $(x,y)$ and $g$ is (strictly) positive there. So we have a strictly increasing $C^1$ function with zero derivative everywhere except

Comment: for a finite measure set.

Comment: Hmm, thing is I think it only holds that $f$ is differentiable a.e. (and $f’ = g$ a.e.). In particular we can’t conclude $f$ is $C^1$.

Comment: Really? I think $g$ being continuous means $f' = g$ everywhere, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Oh damn I missed that $g$ was continuous. In that case you’re right - this should be a counterexample, nicely done. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: Added. I was just skeptical of the validity of my answer due to what davidlowryduda said Fejzić and Rinne did (my simple construction seems to do even more).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open and dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with finite measure. Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ be a continuous function with $\{g = 0\} = U^c$. Then define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = g(0)+\int_0^x g(t)dt$. Then $f \in C^1$, and $f' \equiv g$ means $f$ is strictly increasing (since any interval $(x,y)$ contains an interval lying in $U$ on which $g$ is strictly positive). So we have a strictly increasing $C^1$ function with zero derivative everywhere except for a finite measure set.

Answer (score 13):

There was a series of articles in the Mathematical Monthly that considered near variants of this problem. These were

1. Jingcheng Tong & Peter A. Braza (1997) A Converse of the
   Mean Value Theorem, The American Mathematical Monthly, 104:10, 939-942, DOI:
   10.1080/00029890.1997.11990743

   In this article, Tong and Braza give two forms of converse to the mean value theorem. They say that a differentiable function $f$ on $(a, b)$ satisfies the *Weak Form* of the converse at a point $c \in (a, b)$ if $f'(c) = \frac{f(\beta) - f(\alpha)}{\beta - \alpha}$ for some interval $(\alpha, \beta) \subset (a, b)$, and $f$ satisfies the *Strong Form* if in addition $c \in (\alpha, \beta)$.

   They show that if $f'(c)$ is not a global extremum of $f$, then the Weak Form is satisfied at $c$. If further $c$ is not an accumulation point of the set $\{ x : f'(x) = f'(c) \}$, then it satisfies the Strong Form.
2. J. M. Borwein & Xianfu Wang (1998) The Converse of the Mean Value
   Theorem May Fail Generically, The American Mathematical Monthly, 105:9, 847-848, DOI:
   10.1080/00029890.1998.12004975

   In this article, Borwein and Wang give an example that has a dense, uncountable set of points $c$ that fail the Weak Form (as described above), and thus are not *mean value points* (or what is sometimes called *mean value abscissas*). But this set still has measure $0$.
3. H. Fejzić & D. Rinne (1999) More on a Mean Value Theorem Converse, The
   American Mathematical Monthly, 106:5, 454-455, DOI: 10.1080/00029890.1999.12005069

   In this article (which is one of those examples of an article in the AMM that casually includes pretty sophisticated math), Fejzić and Rinne describe a construction of a function $f$ that is strictly increasing but which has zero derivative on a set of positive measure.

   They also show that the Lebesgue measure of points $c$ that *are* mean value abscissas is positive.

In short, it's not true that almost every (in the Lebesgue measure sense) point is a mean value abscissa.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer! I unfortunately do not have access to the paper, so just to confirm - is the function you mention in (3) continuously differentiable?

Comment: @NateRiver Oh, I'm glad you clarified as I forgot that condition in the question. No, it's not continuously differentiable. Further, it does not seem possible to modify their construction in a straightforward way to preserve continuity of the derivative. So my answer is a related-but-not-complete answer.