# Converse of mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

*Note: This is an attempt to narrow down conditions under which the conjecture stated in this previous [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401602/converse-of-mean-value-theorem-almost-everywhere) is true. As stated, it is false as shown by the counterexample provided in the answers by the user mathworker21.*

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function.

We say a point $c \in \mathbb R$ is a *mean value point* of $f$ if there exists an open interval $(a,b)$ containing $c$ such that $f’(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.

**Question:** Suppose $f’^{-1} (x)$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$. Is it true that almost every point in $\mathbb R$ is a mean value point of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so.  what about $x^3$ ?  The derivative is $3x^2$ and it takes on any value at most twice, but it's value at 0 is 0 and there are not values so that $a^3 - b^3 = 0$

Comment: Right, so $0$ is not a mean value point, but I think in this case every other value is, in particular almost every value is a mean value point.

Comment: For any point $c \neq 0$, $c$ is the mean value point of $(-\sqrt{3}c,\sqrt{3}c)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the 'almost every'.  I thought it seemed too simple

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample.

Let $C$ be a Cantor set with positive Lebesgue measure. The function $x \mapsto d(x,C)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, null on $C$ and (strictly) positive on $\mathbb{R} \setminus C$.

Let $f$ be an antiderivative. Since $\mathbb{R} \setminus C$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, the function $f$ is (strictly) increasing. Hence points of $C$ (where $f'$ vanishes) cannot be mean value points of $f$.

[Old answer below, actually  to another question]

The function $g : (a,b) \mapsto \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ is continuous on the connected set $D := \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2\ : a < b\}$, so $g(D)$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, hence an interval.

By definition of $f'$, the set $f'(\mathbb{R})$ is contained in the closure of the interval $g(D)$. Hence $f'(\mathbb{R}) \setminus g(D)$ contains at most two points.

Comment: you probably missed $c\in (a,b)$ condition

Comment: Ah, yes. I will think more about it.

Comment: @Nate River I think that I now answer the right question.

Comment: But you missed the condition that $\{t\in \mathbb R: f'(t)=x\}$ should have measure $0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.